# Brightness Keys(Fn+F5, Fn+F6) Not Working on ASUS K501UX in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: laptop, brightness, asus, 16.10

When I press the function keys + F5, F6 for brightness control nothing happens. This works fine in Windows. I ended up making a shortcut to the Brightness & Lock settings on my Unity bar, but this is *far* from ideal. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `acpi_osi=` boot parameter. It works for most of ASUS models, but not all.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked! For others wondering: gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub then sudo update-grub - put the acpi_osi= in the command line like so:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

Answer (score 2):

The fix as mentioned by Pilot6 above is this:

`gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` then change the command line to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

and run `sudo update-grub`